# Cloning model with hasMany related models in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, belongs-to

(Looks like I solved my own problem, if only someone could answer question in the **Update 1** and check my own solution for the problem in **Update 2**. Thank you.)
Trying to clone Invoice model with related Items.
Getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()` error. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Invoice.php**

```
public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

**Item.php**

```
public function invoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}
```

**InvoiceController.php**

```
public function copy(Invoice $invoice){
    $copy = $invoice->replicate(['number']);
    foreach($invoice->items as $item) $copy->items()->associate($item);
    $copy->push();
    return redirect('/invoices/' . $copy->id . '/edit')->with('alerts', ['Invoice has been copied']);
}
```

**Update 1**

I guess, I semi-figured this out. Parent cloned model should be saved first to receive an ID before calling for `saveMany` on children nodes. Looks like `push` method cannot be used here either.
I am still puzzled, why I cannon use `associate` and `push` methods in this scenario...

**Update 2**

Turns out this method was not creating cloned items, instead, it was updating the ones it was trying to clone, which is weird... What I did is `replicate` items inside a loop (replication does not exists in relations like `belongsTo`). So my final code is:

```
public function copy(Invoice $invoice){
    $copy = $invoice->replicate(['number', 'url_key']);
    $copy->url_key = strtolower(str_random(8));
    $copy->save();
    foreach($invoice->items as $item) $copy->items()->save($item->replicate(['type_id']));
    return redirect('/invoices/' . $copy->id . '/edit')->with('alerts', ['Invoice has been copied']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **save()** instead of **associate()**:

```
$copy->items()->save($item);
```

or **saveMany()** that internally calls **save()** for a collection of models:

```
$copy->items()->saveMany($invoice->items);
```

Comment: I did try using `save` method prior to posting here, but it looks like this method cannot "associate" items with invoice. `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'invoice_id' cannot be null (SQL: update `items` set `invoice_id` = , `updated_at` = 2016-10-01 00:00:00 where `id` = 1)`

Comment: Also if I use your second method with `saveMany` throws another error: `Method saveMany does not exist.` Looks like its a typo in your second method, should be :`$copy->items()->saveMany($invoice->items);`? In that case the same error as for the first method...

Comment: I have also tried setting NULL as a default for invoice_id field and procedure was able to complete, but as I have suspected, it just created items with NULL invoice_id field (I wondered if this field gets populated afterwards).

Comment: There was a typo with saveMany, now it will exist. You should also update the copies of items with the id of the new invoice unless you want the copies to point to the old one.

Comment: I have already noted the type in the same comment I refereed to non-existent method. Also, I thought the whole point of cloning in the form of `$copy->items()->save()` was in order NOT to update items with the ID of $copy manually.

Comment: You clone an object with all its attributes except ID. If any field needs a new value you need to provide it explicitly

Comment: This is incorrect, @jedrzej ,`invoice_id` (in my case) is getting auto-filled when I use it on the relationship.